# Where are the H and L from in the weather app?

Tags: weather.app

The weather app is currently listing temps as follows: current 10, H 25, L 5.
Great - it was indeed 25 this afternoon and is currently 10. But when you scroll through the horizontal hourly temps for the next 24 hrs, tonight’s overnight low is…10. The weather channel link doesn’t list a low of 5 either. So it was 5… last night? In which “day” or 24 hr period was it 5?

I’m a farmer - I have crops and livestock with breaking points. This sort of thing really matters and effects the work I do and how I care for things.

Update: the current high is listed as 36 but the hourly temps for the next 24 hrs only go to 34, and it sure wasn’t 36 today. I have some fundamental misunderstanding of H/L is measuring it referring to??[image]

Comment: It might help if you post some screenshots showing us what you’re seeing.

Comment: This doesn’t directly answer your question, but I would like to gently encourage you to consider the built-in weather app as a consumer-grade product which is not intended to be relied upon for mission-critical operations. It sounds like there are real-world consequences to you if you receive inaccurate weather data. I’d invite you to consider exploring business-grade weather products from third-party manufacturers which can give you stronger assurances and which, presumably, would have more direct technical support where you can ask questions about how data is obtained and displayed.

Comment: I have another app I use too, this is just irritating me. I have multiple apps and the built in one is the most accurate! I just want to know where they’re pulling numbers.

Comment: My assumption is that the 5 is the forecasted low for the current day. Your screenshot shows that it’s 7:00 PM. If you  if you look back at the actual temps for the preceding 19 hours, did the temperature ever get close to 5 degrees?

Comment: That’s what I thought but…. Like right now it says the H is 36, but it was only 27 yesterday and the hourly for this afternoon only goes to 34. Right now the low is 9, and it was 9 around 10pm last night. The only thing I can think of is that it’s a H/L for 12 hrs before and after the current time, or the previous 24 hrs or something, rather than the daytime H for “Sunday” and overnight low for “Sunday night”.